# Firebase Cloud Functions: Error 500 despite successful results

Tags: node.js, python-3.x, axios, google-cloud-functions

I am building the backend of a webscraping application on Firebase Cloud Functions and consists of two functions:

1. WEBSCRAPER FUNCTION, written in Python3 using BeautifulSoup, to scrape contents from multiple pages (easily around 500 pages)，and returns scraped contents as json
2. SCHEDULED FUNCTION, written in Nodejs, that calls the webscraper in item 1 at hourly intervals, and updates Firestore with the scraped contents.

The scheduled function uses Axios to perform the get requests.

**Problem** I am consistently receiving the following error in the scheduled function irregularly. This happens sometimes at every call and sometimes not even once, making it really difficult to debug. The irregularities also occurs across dev, staging, prod environments:

```
//err.response
{ status: 500,
  statusText: 'Internal Server Error',
  headers: 
   { 'x-cloud-trace-context': '2f22d7fc6a9044dcfc31acafc2d50e54',
     date: 'Thu, 23 Apr 2020 04:45:39 GMT',
     'content-type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
     server: 'Google Frontend',
     'content-length': '323',
     'alt-svc': 'quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43",h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q049=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q048=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-T050=":443"; ma=2592000',
     connection: 'close' },
  config: 
   { url: 'CLOUD_FUNCTIONS_URL',
     method: 'get',
     params: {//params}
}
```

Whenever such errors occur in the SCHEDULED FUNCTION, no error actually occurred in the WEBSCRAPER FUNCTION, ie Firebase Cloud Function consoles prints `Function execution took XXXX ms, finished with status code: 200` for the WEBSCRAPER FUNCTION.

I have also done checks on the WEBSCRAPER FUNCTION that when it finished with `status code: 200`, **valid results are returned correctly**.

Portion of my code as follows:

```
//In the SCHEDULED FUNCTION where I call the WEBSCRAPER FUNCTION
function getContentPromise(param1, param2) {
    let url = //WEBSCRAPER FUNCTION's url
    let parameters = {param1: param1, param2: param2};
    let config = {
        params: parameters,
    }
    return axios.get(url, config)
    .then((response) => {
        return response.data
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log('Retrying...', err.response) //Error thrown here
        return getContentPromise(param1, param2)
    })
}

//In the WEBSCRAPER FUNCTION

//At main.py
def scrape(request):
    response_object = scrape(request)
    return jsonify(response_object)

//At the scrape function
def scrape(request):
    param1 = request.args.get('param1')
    param2 = request.args.get('param2')

    //Some scraping stuff happening here using beautifulsoup

    response_object = {}
    response_object[constants.status_code_key] = 200
    response_object['contents'] = contents //contents in json

    return response_object
```

Answer (score 0):

Which firebase plan are you on? Outbound network requests to non-google services are only allowed in [Blaze plan](https://firebase.google.com/pricing).

You can make sure if that is the case with your app if its works in local environment but gives 500 response code in production.

Comment: all three of my environments are on blaze. And I'm getting the said error in production as well. It happens irregularly, sometimes in dev and staging but not in production. Sometimes in production and dev but not in staging.

Comment: It is difficult to suggest a proper fix from my standpoint. Maybe somebody from firebase will come along and shed better insight. In the meantime though, you can use a workaround by reconfiguring the schedule interval and storing scraped data to a container or temp storage until next successful fetch. You can then pipe that buffer as a backup from your catch block. Checkout [managing firebase resources](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2mjfI0FYP7Y) to make sure you don't run out of disk storage, given you're scraping hundreds of pages.